# Proof of $(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})/(n\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: group-theory

Prove of  $(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})/(n\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$

I have no idea how to go about with this

Comment: Do you know the third isomorphism theorem?

Comment: I haven't encuontered it

Comment: Here it is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem#Groups

Comment: Do you know the first Isomorphism Theorem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is true because of the [Third Isomorphism Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem#Third_isomorphism_theorem). These theorems can be really helpful when you're proving isomorphisms, so it's important to know all of them:

- [First Isomorphism Theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/First_Isomorphism_Theorem/Groups): The quotient ring of the domain and kernel of a homomorphism is isomorphic to the image.
- [Second Isomorphism Theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Second_Isomorphism_Theorem/Groups): For $H \leq G$ and $N \trianglelefteq G$, $\frac{H}{H \cap N} \cong \frac{HN}{N}$.
- [Third Isomorphism Theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Third_Isomorphism_Theorem/Groups): For $H, N \trianglelefteq G$ and $N \subseteq H$, $\frac{G/N}{H/N} \cong \frac G H$

Thus, using the Third Isomorphism Theorem, we get $\frac{\Bbb{Z}/m\Bbb{Z}}{n\Bbb{Z}/m\Bbb{Z}} \cong \frac{\Bbb{Z}}{n\Bbb{Z}}$.

P.S. If you want a better explanation of the Isomorphism Theorems, I suggest [reading about it from this online textbook](http://abstract.ups.edu/aata/homomorph.html).